# I cannot read string after realloc

Tags: c, string, struct, realloc

I have this function, I realocate memory, but when i want to read string it doesn't work=>error
Student is a Struct

```
void insertStudent(Student **myStudents, int *size)
{
    int newSize = *size + 1;
    *myStudents = (Student*)realloc(myStudents, newSize*sizeof(Student));
    printf("Enter your grade: ");
    scanf("%f", &(*myStudents)[*size - 1].nota);

    printf("Enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*myStudents)[newSize-1].firstName);


    printf("Enter your second name: ");
    scanf("%s", &(*myStudents)[*size - 1].lastName);
    //Generate a new code
    /*int code = rand() % 1+1000;
    int ok = 0;
    while (ok == 0)
    {
        ok = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++)
            if ((*myStudents)[i].cod == code)
            {
                code = rand() % 1 + 1000;
                ok = 0;
            }
    }*/
    (*myStudents)[*size-1].cod = 7;
    printf("Your code is: %d. Do not forget it! ", 7);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add compiler error in the question?

Comment: You need to decide which of `*size - 1` and `newSize - 1` is correct and use that consistently.  I think it is the second, but look carefully.

Comment: Sidenote: **`realloc()` can fail.** In that case it returns `NULL`, *and the old pointer remains valid*. As you'd need to `free()` the **old** pointer, it's basically a memory leak waiting to happen to assign the return value of `realloc()` to the same pointer you passed as parameter.

Comment: as others will (or have already) point out: Please don't cast the return of `mailloc`, `realloc` and `calloc` when writing plain old C. The cast is required in C++, but is considered bad practice in C as it can hide errors (especially pre C11)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem nitpick: implicit function declaration is already wrong (requiring a diagnostic) in C99, making the "canonic" argument kind of weak. Nevertheless, I still think [casting to/from `void *` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713482/2371524).

Comment: @MayankJain.: I guess you have resolved the problem you had.

Answer (score 4):

```
void insertStudent(Student **myStudents, int *size)
{
    *myStudents = (Student*)realloc(myStudents, newSize*sizeof(Student));
                               //   ^ <- look here
```

This is a *pointer to a pointer* to your students. `realloc()` expects the pointer to the data originally allocated, so you most certainly have to pass `*myStudents` here!

Also change the code to use a temporary variable. `realloc()` may return `NULL` on error, in which case the original memory is still allocated and you have to `free()` it.

For calculating the size, it's better to use the expression syntax of `sizeof` (`newSize * sizeof **myStudents`) because this prevents errors when later changing the type.

For sizes, you should always use `size_t`, as this is guaranteed to hold any possible size of an object (`int` is not ...)

Further side note: converting to and from `void *` is **implicit** in C and it's [arguably better style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) not to write this cast explicitly.

All in all, the code should be written like this

```
void insertStudent(Student **myStudents, size_t *size)
{
    size_t newSize = *size + 1;
    Student *newStudents = realloc(*myStudents, newSize * sizeof *newStudents);
    if (!newStudents)
    {
        free(*myStudents);
        *myStudents = 0;
        return; // check for this error in calling code
    }
    *myStudents = newStudents;
    *size = newSize;
    // [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are reallocting to `myStudents`. It is not your intention and it is not possible.

From [**standard 7.22.3.5**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5)

> `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);`
>
> Otherwise, *if `ptr` does not match a pointer earlier returned by a
>   memory management function*, or if the space has been deallocated by a
>   call to the free or realloc function, *the behavior is undefined*. If
>   memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is not
>   deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Earlier you had undefined behavior, you didn't pass the originally allocated memory's address. Rather you passed a local variable. You had *undefined behavior*.

```
Student* t = realloc(*myStudents, newSize*sizeof(Student))
if(t){
  *myStudents = t;
  (*size)++;
}
else {
   perror("realloc failed");
   free(*myStudents);
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also as you are increasing the memory you should do increase it if the call is successful. Then consistently access `*size-1` throughout the code, it is easier to handle and go through.

The right way to do it shown above. In case `realloc` returns `NULL` you won't lose the reference to the already allocated memory. Also with this comes the advise to check the return value of `realloc`. Casting is redundant in this case - don't do it.

In the `scanf` you can simply write

```
scanf("%s",(*myStudents)[newSize-1].firstName);
```

otherwise you were passing `char (*)[]` it expects `char*`.

Comment: @MareșȘtefan.: Hope there is some memory allocated and it is not just pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`realloc()` needs pointer to the memory to be reallocated which is `*myStudents` and not `myStudents`.

Change

```
 *myStudents = (Student*)realloc(myStudents, newSize*sizeof(Student));
```

to

```
 *myStudents = (Student*)realloc(*myStudents, newSize*sizeof(Student));
```